# Finding consecutive sequence of ascending strings in an ArrayList and separate them into two ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

Pretty straight:
I'm trying to find a consecutive sequence of Strings using compareTo and save them into two different arraylists.
Each ArrayList should continue adding strings ONLY if the next string is lexicographically equal or greater than the previous one. i.e: if the ArrayList contains [Aaaaa,Bbbbb,Ccccc,Aaaaa,Bbbbb,Aaaa,Fffff] I want them to separate them into two ArrayList as:
ArrayList 1 contains the first sequence of consecutive ascending strings: [Aaaaa,Bbbbb,Ccccc]. Then, ArrayList 2 should contain the immediate following consecutive sequence of ascending string: [Aaaaa,Bbbbb], and then again switch to the ArrayList 1 and append the next sequence, so now ArrayList 1 should be: [Aaaaa,Bbbbb,Ccccc] + [Aaaa,Fffff], and so on.
I've tried this:

```
static ArrayList<String> separateArray(ArrayList<String> list){
        ArrayList<String> F1 =  new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> F2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<list.size()-1;i++){
            if((list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1))<=0))
                F1.add(list.get(i));
            
            F1.add(list.get(i+1));
            for(int j=i;j<list.size()-1;j++){
                if((list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(j+1))<=0))
                    F2.add(list.get(j));
                
            }
            
                
        }
}
```

I've tried a lot of other things and methods to get this done, but I just can't figure it out. How could I implement like a "switch" from adding to F1 to F2 and then again F1 and so on?

Comment: what should be the return value? Its supposed to be `ArrayList<String>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you'd have to know what's the current target List, F1 or F2. Could be

- another variable `ArrayList<String> current` where you write to, you assign it alternating F1 or F2.
- a boolean flag `writingToF1`, each time you write to a list, you check it, `if(writingToF1) {F1.add} else {F2.add}`, you have to set it accordingly when switching sequences
- by recursion, using method parameters to switch lists.

Like this.  The `break`looks ugly, though.

```
static void separate(ArrayList<String> source, int currIndex, ArrayList<String> left, ArrayList<String> right) {
    for(int i=currIndex; i<source.size()-1;i++){
        // put stuff into left, when end of sequence reached continue with switched lists
        separate(source, i, right, left);
        break;
    }
}

static void separateArray(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayList<String> F1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> F2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    separate(list, 0, F1, F2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use recursion

```
static int compare(List<String> F, List<String> list, int segmentStart) {
    int i = segmentStart;
    for (i = segmentStart; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        if ((list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) <= 0)) {
            F.add(list.get(i));
        } else {
            F.add(list.get(i));
            break;
        }
    }
    // if list size is 1 or 2 then compare manually
    if (list.size() == 1) {
        F.add(list.get(0));
    // if list size is 2 then compare last F element amd last list element (first list elemrnt was compered in for loop)
    } else if (list.size() == 2 && (F.get(F.size() - 1).compareTo(list.get(i)) <= 0)) {
        F.add(list.get(i));
    }
    return i + 1;
}

static void separateArray(List<String> F1, List<String> F2, List<String> list) {
    int firstSegmentIndex = compare(F1, list, 0);
    if (firstSegmentIndex < list.size()) {
        int secSegmentIndex = compare(F2, list, firstSegmentIndex);
        if (secSegmentIndex + 1 <= list.size()) {
            separateArray(F1, F2, list.subList(secSegmentIndex, list.size()));
        }
    }
}
```